# Changing mp3 file of jplayer through ajax

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have a jplayer component in my website. I want to change the variable of mp3 which is sky.mp3 dynamically, that is through an ajax function. How can I do it with jquery?

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    mp3:"sky.mp3"
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    keyEnabled: true
});

<div id="cp_container_1">

    <a class="cp-play" onClick="return false;" href="#"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the docs for jPlayer: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-setMedia

Use the jPlayer.setMedia method to do so. Assuming you're using the jQuery jPlayer plugin:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('setMedia',{
    mp3: '/path/to/another-sky.mp3'
});
```

Assuming you're playing around from jPlayer's demo (http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-05/), there are other methods available from jPlayer's API:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('pause');
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play');
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('volume',10);
```

Etc... just make sure jPlayer emits its ready event before you attempt to interface with it.